# ¿Cómo extraer la información de una página WEB utilizando importxlm?

Tags: html, xml, google-hoja-de-cálculo, xpath, scraping

Necesito conseguir la fórmula para extraer lo que aparece luego de seleccionar `recoger` y hacer `click` en el botón `+` (adjunto imagen):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando inspecciono la página para verificar el código, no me aparece lo que está después del botón `+`, solo aparece si yo mismo le doy click al botón y luego inspecciono, al hacer eso, me aparece el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado de todo, pero siempre me aparece en `Google Sheets` el contenido vacío. Tal vez no lo estoy anexando correctamente con lo símbolos correctos.

Comment: Hola Oscar, bienvenido a SOes. La verdad no se entiende muy bien tu pregunta ni lo que deseas conseguir. Tómate un tiempo, analiza cuál es el problema específico que tienes, sitúa el enlace a la página, sitúa parte del código que estás intentando, lee [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y después edita la pregunta para describir exactamente el problema que tienes.

Comment: Quizás haga falta estar familiarizado con [tag:google-hoja-de-cálculo], la función `importxml`, las herramientas de desarrollos de chrome para entender la pregunta. En cualquier caso, ayudaría mucho mejorar la redacción y reestructurar el contenido, quizás empezar por mencionar que estas usando las hojas de cálculo de Google. incluir la fórmula que has intentado detacando el xpath que obtuviste al inspeccionar el código usando Chrome, así como una breve descripción de tus esfuerzos de búsqueda/investigación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tl;Dr:

Usando Chrome,

1. Abre el URL de los datos / página web.
2. Oprime <kbd>F12</kbd> para abrir las herramientas de desarrollador de Chrome
3. Oprime <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> para abrir el menú de comandos
4. Empieza escribiendo `javascript`, selecciona **Disable JavaScript** (¿inhabilitar JavaScript?), y luego presiona <kbd>Enter</kbd> para ejecutar la instrucción. Ahora JavaScript está inhabilitado.

JavaScript permanecerá inhabilitado en esa pestaña mientras tengas abiertas las herramientas de desarrollador.

Recarga la página para ver si se muestra el contenido que quieres importar. Si se muestra, podría ser posible importarlo con las funciones de la hoja de cálculo de Google, si no se muestra, no será posible hacerlo por lo que deberás buscar otra alternativa.

---

Las funciones de hoja de cálculo incluidas en las hojas de cálculo de Google (Google Sheets) sólo pueden acceder al código fuente el documento referido por el URL. El problema de usar las herramientas de inspección de código de Chrome es que este muestra el DOM actual, es decir, el resultado del motor web el cual ejecuta el JavaScript ya sea incluido en línea en el HTML como el que se encuentra en recursos enlazados así como por las modificaciones hechas por extensiones del navegador.

Para encontrar el `xpath` usando la herramienta de inspección del navegador, primero inhabilita JavaScript y las extensiones del navegador. Lo más sencillo para esto es abrir la página en modo incógnito con todas las extensiones inhabilitadas, luego usa el comando `javascript` para inhabilitar JavaScript

Si el contenido se muestra con JavaScript inhabilitado, lo siguiente sería hacer la prueba de encontrar el `xpath` con las herramientas de desarrollador y si este se encuentra, probar con `IMPORTXML`. Si no funciona podría ser que el contenido que se desea importar está en una sección del código que no cumple con las reglas de XML.

Referencia

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Comment: Estuve investigando un poco cuando entendí la pregunta (el OP me envió un correo mejor explicado). Al inicio de la aplicación hay una llamada que retorna un `JSON` con todos los productos. En este aparece cada menú con la relación de `ids` que incluye, y cada uno de esos `ids` está incluido en el `HTML` (básicamente un menú está conformado por otros productos que están en la misma página). Creo que con esta información a lo mejor podrías ayudarlo más, pero involucraría leer el `JSON`, acceder a la lista de ids y recorrer el DOM seleccionado esos ids y su contenido con `importxml`.

Comment: @ElChiniNet Las hoja de cálculo de Google no pueden leer las respuestas de llamadas, quizás usando Google Apps Script y en específico UrlFetchApp sea posible obtener el JSON.

Comment: Quizás le convendría usar `ImportJSON`. Se trata de un proyecto de código abierto que está en github el cual me parece que es bastante popular.

Comment: Sí, ese fue el script que encontré, pero está pensado para tomar la respuesta y situarla en las celdas. Lo que mirando el código ser podría intentar tomar la parte de la llamada. De todas formas, conllevaría mucho trabajo y creo que debería cubrirse con varias preguntas del OP. Creo que con lo que le has dado lo encaminas bastante.

Comment: ImporJSON como proyecto incluye una una función para desarrollares pero de uno dedicar tiempo a entender como funciona.